# How to make statement work only for the selected level in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

So Here I have this code

```
 if collision == PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed {
            print("SUCCESS")
            win()
            if currentLevel < 10 {
                currentLevel += 1
            }
```

And basically this statement works for every single level that I have .
I want to make it like this for only one level

```
 if collision == PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed| PhysicsCategory.Bottle {
            print("SUCCESS")
            win()
            if currentLevel < 10 {
                currentLevel += 1
            }
```

But If I will use it it will mean that the collision with bottle will be needed in every single level , however I want to use it only in one level

I am using swift

thank you!

FOR @Mundi

Here is code in GameScene

```
 import SpriteKit
Game scene
protocol EventListenerNode {
    func didMoveToScene()
}
protocol InteractiveNode {
    func interact()
}

struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None:  UInt32 = 0
    static let Cat:   UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
    static let Block: UInt32 = 0b10 // 2
    static let Bed:   UInt32 = 0b100 // 4
    static let Edge:  UInt32 = 0b1000 // 8
    static let Label: UInt32 = 0b10000 // 16
    static let Spring:UInt32 = 0b100000 //32
    static let Hook: UInt32 = 0b1000000 //64
    static let Bottle: UInt32 = 0b10000000 //64

}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var bedNode: BedNode!
    var catNode: CatNode!
    var lineNode: LineNode!
    var bottleNode: BottleNode!
    var desiredCollision = PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed


    var playable = true

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Calculate playable margin
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let maxAspectRatioHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
        let playableMargin: CGFloat = (size.height - maxAspectRatioHeight)/2
        let playableRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin,
                                  width: size.width, height: size.height-playableMargin*2)
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: playableRect)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge

        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*", using: { node, _ in
            if let eventListenerNode = node as? EventListenerNode {
                eventListenerNode.didMoveToScene()


            }

        })

        bedNode = childNode(withName: "bed") as! BedNode
        catNode = childNode(withName: "//cat_body") as! CatNode
        bottleNode = childNode(withName: "bottle") as! BottleNode




   func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        if collision == PhysicsCategory.Label | PhysicsCategory.Edge {

            let labelNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Label ?
                contact.bodyA.node :
                contact.bodyB.node

            if let message = labelNode as? MessageNode {
                message.didBounce()
            }
        }

        if !playable {
            return
        }


        if currentLevel == 20 { // or whatever level you want
            desiredCollision |= PhysicsCategory.Bottle

        }

        if collision == desiredCollision {
            print ("Win")
            win()


        } else if collision == PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Edge {
            print("FAIL")
            lose()
```

and here is the code from my BottleBode

import SpriteKit

```
class BottleNode: SKSpriteNode, EventListenerNode {
    func didMoveToScene() {
        print("bottle added to scene")

        let bedBodySize = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 30.0)
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bedBodySize)
        physicsBody!.isDynamic = true

        physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bottle
        physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Block | PhysicsCategory.Edge | PhysicsCategory.Spring | PhysicsCategory.Spring
        parent!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bed | PhysicsCategory.Edge

    }
}
```

I did as you told me however it still doesn't work, and when the CatNode touches the ground I have lose condition and I am receiving an error.

Here is a picture of how it doesn't work
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JrMJ.png

and here is an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VGRd.png

Could you please tell me what wrong ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible without a special variable and more succinctly:

```
var desiredCollision = PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed
if currentLevel == 7 { // or whatever level you want
   desiredCollision |= PhysicsCategory.Bottle
}

if collision = desiredCollision { 
// ...
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my answer. I thought there was a better way, but couldn't think of one.

Comment: @Mundi Thank you!
Where would be the best place to insert it?

Comment: @Mundi , right after it ?or Instead ? sorry I am new to programming :(

Comment: @Mundi 
Dear Mundi , I updated my post with the code you provided me, however It doesnt work , I think I could of done something wrong , could you please check it , I would be very pleased.

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested if-else statements to first check if it's the special level, then decide which version to use based on the result of that. It would look something like this:

```
var useSpecialCollision: bool // Change this to true/false based on when the level changes

if useSpecialCollision == true {

     if collision == PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed| PhysicsCategory.Bottle {
            print("SUCCESS")
            win()
            if currentLevel < 10 {
                currentLevel += 1
            }
     }

} else {

     if collision == PhysicsCategory.Cat | PhysicsCategory.Bed {
        print("SUCCESS")
        win()
        if currentLevel < 10 {
            currentLevel += 1
        }
     }

}
```

This puts your if statements/code into another if statement to determine which code to run. Not very complicated... Not the neatest either...

Comment: Nik, Could you please Check my post above, I updated it as Mundi suggested , I think I have mistake somewhere ?

Thank you

Comment: @KateYashenko Whats the problem with it?

Comment: It doesn't work, I provided pictures above . Please check it

Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe I made some mistake , maybe it Bottle node ?  

Or somewhere else ?

@Nik